# A word or an idiom for when you try to squeeze out some soap and you get shot with it instead

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

I am wondering what would be the proper word or an idiom corresponding to the following:

You are trying to squeeze out some hand soap or hand sanitizer from a push down bottle, like this:

[image: push-down bottle]

But because the nozzle is dried out, the liquid instead of coming down on your hand, shoots straight, for example hitting your face or clothes.

It happened recently at a meeting I attended, and I could not find proper words to explain it to another person. Squirt comes to mind, but I wonder if there is a better word or expression for it emphasizing that the dispenser did not work as intended.

Comment: Murphy's Law. The Second Law of Thermodynamics. S**t happens.

Comment: Heh - true. I am looking more what words would you use to explain to someone what happened. For example if everybody is laughing, and you need to explain what happened to someone who did not see it.

Comment: I would go with *squirt*.

Comment: How about "I've just had a liquid soap bottle *malfunction*."

Comment: A little mishap.

Comment: I know of no idiomatic express for this, but there should be one. It's a common enough event. It's happened to me with [ketchup](http://www.anything4restaurants.com/_imageresize/product.aspx?src=132244.jpg) – it can lead to some awkward moments!

Comment: @user3169 can you make it an answer? Looks like most people prefer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that kind of bottle, it SHOULD "squirt", but in the right direction. You might, for instance, explain to someone "squirt some on your hand".

Try "spurted out". This has a bit more forceful of connotation than "squirted". Feel how the word feels on your lips—the "P" sound more closely mimics a sudden outrush from a stopped-up passageway.

Comment: I like that one, I found somewhere example with "lava spurting out of the volcano" which does  seem to go well with forcing through blocked passageway

Answer (score 1):

I am not native but the words that work in here could be

> The soap could spray over yourself

or to spill on and to shoot out

Comment: Yeah, I did not think of spray - I think it conveys meaning pretty good, even though it is a more of a jet you're hit with

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with *squirt*. It is the best word I can think of.